# Step out of a loop in Visual Studio's debugger

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

Is there a similar functionality like the step out of a function to step out of a loop?

I am currently using VS2005, but am interested to know whether MS presented the option in any of the versions.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, there isn't such functionality in any version of VS.Net to date.  Setting a breakpoint after the loop or using 'Run to cursor' are both reasonable workarounds.

Comment: "Reasonable" is in the eye of the beholder. I was looking for a solution that would involve 2 keystrokes like `shift`+`F11`

Comment: @Ofek - very true - which is most likely why there's no shift+F11 equivalent for loops - the debugger would have to either figure out all possible places you can end up after the loop or single-step repeatedly until the loop is left.

Comment: @Will A - Regarding the return part at least I don't think the debugger needs to perform any differently than in the function case since it needs to perform the code anyhow and it might hit a debugcheck during the execution of the function.

Comment: "Run to cursor" solves it with 1 mouseclick and  Ctrl+F10 , it's reasonable simple

Comment: @Shaihi - If the beholder thinks it is reasonable to write a macro or add-in to solve this then the beholder is either spending way to much quality time with his debugger or needs glasses to see the beauty of the most pragmatic solution. Cheers

Comment: @Berry  -I'm not loosing sleep over it;)

@nos - I missed the run to cursor in the answer - I will check it out. thx